# Is it okay to submit manuscript to arXiv after "revise and resubmit"?

Tags: publications, journals, copyright, arxiv

I've read [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/44524/if-my-paper-is-accepted-in-a-springer-journal-can-i-submit-my-version-of-the-ma) about how some publishers (e.g., Springer) allows authors to submit to arXiv before journal submission, but they make authors wait for a year after acceptance to submit to arXiv.

My question is: Is it okay to submit to arXiv *during* the time when the paper is under consideration by the journal, for example after it has been "revised and resubmitted" but before final decision?

Comment: This depends on the journal, and whether they consider articles posted on arXiv to be prior publication. See [this list on wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_academic_journals_by_preprint_policy) for some examples of journal policies.

Comment: @ff524 I guess the "prior publication" issue should not play into the question whether one can resubmit the revised version to arXiv. If it wasn't a prior publication before review, it shouldn't be one after. I think the relevant question is whether a journal can / does claim some sort of copyright or IP over the changes that have been made due to reviewer recommendations. My inclination is "no", but I am not a lawyer.

Comment: There are three separate questions: is it ok, is it legal, and does the publisher really care. The first one is a matter of opinion. The second one may depend on the circumstances (e.g. the country you work in; the country the publisher operates in; your employer and funder(s)).

Comment: @xLeitix you're right, I misunderstood the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The version you mention is called a [postprint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postprint). Publishers have various policies about them. You can use [the SHERPA/RoMEO service](http://www.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/) to get a summary of the policy in place for a particular journal.

Here is an example of what you get for Lecture Notes in Computer Science, edited by Springer:

[image: example policy for LNCS, Springer]

As noted in the comments, you do not necessarily need to abide by these policies, for instance if your funder has set up an open access policy.

Comment: I'm not referring to the final draft post-refereeing, but rather an intermediate version (perhaps after one round of refereeing).

Comment: Ok. Intuitively I would still consider that it falls in the "postprint" category as some input from the journal was included in the document, but IANAL… In doubt, just upload it, you should be fine.

Comment: *you do not necessarily need to abide by these policies, for instance if your funder has set up an open access policy.* – Those are not policies, those are what you agree to in the copyright agreement with the journal (which tells you in detail what you are allowed to do, i.e., what you did not agree not to do). If your funder has an open-access policy, this does not change what you are allowed to do by itself. It may affect the copyright agreements you can agree to, however.