Do publishers actually care about arXiv?
For-profit publishers (my experience is mostly with Springer and Elsevier) typically have some conditions on what you can an cannot do to self-archive your manuscript.
For example, Springer allows you to self-archive on your own website immediately but has sometimes an embargo period for arXiv and similar public repositories.
As far as I understand, you can get around the embargo period by uploading the pre-review text (And I suppose not using the publisher's template is best).
Placing your articles on public repositories is a common practice, so I am wondering: what happens when inevitably someone steps out of line and puts on arXiv a version too close to the published manuscript, or does it too early.
Are there documented cases of publishers complaining? And do the publishers simply send a removal request to you/arXiv, or do things get heated?

Springer allows you to self-archive on your own website immediately but has an embargo of 12 months for arXiv and similar public repositories. That's not correct. See https://www.springer.com/gp/editorial-policies/preprint-sharing, you are free to share preprints on the arXiv. See also https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/44524/if-my-paper-is-accepted-in-a-springer-journal-can-i-submit-my-version-of-the-ma

The links you mention are about preprints, and rules for what is a preprint, I am asking a different thing: "what happens when someone accidentally breaks these rules? do publisher come after you?"
I feel it is clear from what I wrote, so I'm not sure how to edit, but I tried to remove any ambiguity.

Not arXiv, but ResearchGate was sued for facilitating unlicensed sharing of papers. Posting this as a comment, because it's unclear to me if any of the alleged infringements were under an embargo period.

Thanks Anyon. Embargo was not of particular interest, I'm wondering in general if publishers care about preprints and it seems they do! A big difference is probably the fact that these were the final manuscript, and not the text recompiled in another template as is the case for arxiv (maybe this is why they don't even accept PDF anymore!)
If you post it as an answer I'll approve it
(sure makes me glad I ignored all those ResearchGate emails saying "we found your full text online!")
